# <tiles:insertTemplate> is slow

Tags: java, jsp, tiles

There seems to be an overhead in  when included file is very large.  This has nothing to do with the contents of the file, just its size, the file has nothing but commented out text

```
<tiles:insertTemplate template="/WEB-INF/very/large/file/with/nothing/but/comments.jsp">
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

Time to insertTemplate is proportionate to the size of the file.

comments.jsp looks like this:

<%--comme

```
nt comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment--%>
<%--comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment
```

comment--%>

Comment: Just for you to know. tiles:insert will "copy" your file into the new one. This explain why it's take time proportionate to the size

Comment: I was hoping the server would "copy" the file into the new one only once, then compile the JSP into a servlet, thus this overhead only happening on the first page request, I'm seeing this overhead upon refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Tomcat (version 7). I solved it setting the development parameter in web.xml to false.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>development</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
...
</servlet>
```